# btrfs still usable after unusual repair?

Tags: usb-drive, btrfs

I had a broken (unmountable) btrfs partition on a USB HDD. The problem had the same error message as described here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182505

dmesg outputted following

```
[   54.371041] BTRFS: device label BackupMobile devid 1 transid 1420 /dev/dm-3
[   54.384764] BTRFS info (device dm-3): disk space caching is enabled
[   54.384767] BTRFS: has skinny extents
[   54.425187] BTRFS error (device dm-3): bad tree block start 15489378549331356982 932187635712
[   54.431990] BTRFS error (device dm-3): bad tree block start 15489378549331356982 932187635712
[   54.432025] BTRFS: failed to read tree root on dm-3
[   54.449061] BTRFS: open_ctree failed
[  199.271168] BTRFS info (device dm-3): enabling auto recovery
[  199.271174] BTRFS info (device dm-3): disabling disk space caching
[  199.271178] BTRFS: has skinny extents
[  199.278451] BTRFS error (device dm-3): bad tree block start 15489378549331356982 932187635712
[  199.279109] BTRFS error (device dm-3): bad tree block start 15489378549331356982 932187635712
[  199.279119] BTRFS: failed to read tree root on dm-3
[  199.279762] BTRFS error (device dm-3): bad tree block start 15489378549331356982 932187635712
[  199.280509] BTRFS error (device dm-3): bad tree block start 15489378549331356982 932187635712
[  199.280518] BTRFS: failed to read tree root on dm-3
[  208.294771] BTRFS: checking UUID tree
```

Smart test passed without issues.

I finally fixed the mount-issue by using *btrfs-zero-log*.
Then I could mount the volume again.

A day later, I encountered the same problem (unmountable, similar error messages and now even a stacktrace in the log).

This time, my problem seems to be "fixed" by just mounting the partition with recovery options *-o recovery*. Now I can access my data again and could even write to the disk (though I didn't check integrity of written/saved data). Linux didn't complain, the dmesg log looks like this now:

```
[32382.410416] BTRFS info (device dm-6): disk space caching is enabled
[32382.410420] BTRFS: has skinny extents
```

I could mount the drive several times without issues (through nautilus/GNOME).

Is it save to continue using the partition? I would just like to keep the snapshots, otherwise I would have re-formatted already. Despite the still passed Smart test, how can I be sure that it's not a hardware failure and btrfs is to blame?

Full dmesg log of a plug-in and mount of the USB HDD in the current state:

```
[32376.048700] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[32376.177756] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[32376.177770] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[32376.177773] usb 3-4: Product: USB3.0 to SATA Bridge
[32376.177775] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: JMicron
[32376.177777] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXX
[32376.178348] usb-storage 3-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[32376.178434] usb-storage 3-4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[32376.178462] scsi host16: usb-storage 3-4:1.0
[32377.688528] scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST2000LM 015-2E8174       0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[32377.689259] sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[32377.699007] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[32377.699386] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[32377.699390] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[32377.699661] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[32377.699664] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[32377.717199]  sdc: sdc1
[32377.729514] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[32382.410416] BTRFS info (device dm-6): disk space caching is enabled
[32382.410420] BTRFS: has skinny extents
```

Edit:

As Shiki pointed out, I did a "surface scan" which seems to be btrfs scrub in the btrfs world. The btrfs scrub log shows 72688 read_errors as well as 72688 uncorrectable_errors. That doesn't look good. I checked against other btrfs hard drives and their scrub logs contained no errors at all.

Full log:

```
scrub status:1
dc484331-2fb1-49a7-8960-38d0b603bd9f:1
|data_extents_scrubbed:85282
|tree_extents_scrubbed:130262
|data_bytes_scrubbed:5386072064
|tree_bytes_scrubbed:2134212608
|read_errors:72688
|csum_errors:0
|verify_errors:0
|no_csum:0
|csum_discards:0
|super_errors:0
|malloc_errors:0
|uncorrectable_errors:72688
|corrected_errors:0
|last_physical:7553941504
|t_start:1502107169
|t_resumed:0
|duration:62
|canceled:1
|finished:1
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Btrfs is still not considered as stable by the industry. So if you care about your data, just put some other FS under it. First of all, just do a full "dd" backup of your disk, then you can mess around since you have a backup. Then you can check the HDD with a "surface scan".

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did a "surface scan" (btrfs scrub) and added the output as an edit.